# fgets_unlocked() for multiple threads reading different files

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, thread-safety, fgets

In the document, I found that `fgets_unlocked()` is not thread-safe.
However, I am not sure that can I use `fgets_unlocked()` without using any lock in a multi-threaded code, but ensure that each thread will access a different file (no two threads will access the same file)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If each thread uses `fgets` of any kind to read from different files and write to different buffers, you're safe. There's nothing shared between threads in that case.